# How to debug sqlplus thin client connection

Tags: ssl, sqlplus

I have installed SQLPLUS thin client on a CentOS. Via the client I am trying to establish a TCPS connection with the Oracle 12c. but when I use the following command I get "ORA-28759: failure to open file" exception. However, when I use the TCP connection it works fine.

This does not work:
sudo sqlplus -s 'user/pwd002@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(PORT=1522)(HOST=test.co.uk))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service101))(SECURITY=(ssl_server_cert_dn=CN=test.co.uk)))'

This Works:
sudo sqlplus -s 'user/pwd002@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(PORT=1521)(HOST=test.co.uk))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service101))(SECURITY=(ssl_server_cert_dn=CN=test.co.uk)))'

Now, I googled and found that above reason can be because the client is unable to locate the wallet location which I checked and is correct as well

in sqlnet.ora
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
wallet_location = (SOURCE=(METHOD= File)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=/home/test/wallet)))

Now, I am not sure if my client is able to locate sqlnet.ora file or not and if not how can I debug it? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are setting the TNS_ADMIN to your wallet path before executing the sqlplus

export TNS_ADMIN=/home/test/wallet

If your Oracle client is 19c+, you can set the wallet path in the connection string through variable 'my_wallet_location'

(SECURITY=(SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=TRUE)(SSL_SERVER_CERT_DN=cn=sales,cn=OracleContext,dc=us,dc=example,dc=com)(MY_WALLET_LOCATION=/home/test/wallet)))

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netag/configuring-naming-methods.html#GUID-36F3A17D-843C-490A-8A23-FB0FE005F8E8